# Regular expression for number between fix set of strings c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

This should be a very simple regular expression but I am very weak at it.

I have a big string coming in and inside that string I have a number between a set of known strings. I would like to extract that number.

For example:

```
some_big_string_start____number_of_records~^~107|^|____some_big_string_end
```

I would like to get `107`. The strings `number_of_records~^~` and `|^|` will always be before and after this number in this big string and they are constant i.e. they will never change.

I tried this link [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/26166304/regular-expression-number-between-2-strings-in-a-url) but was not able to get through.

Please help!

Comment: use http://regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is that your delimiters are also regex metacharacters, so you have to escape them:

```
number_of_records~\^~(\d+)\|\^\|
```

Comment: Thanks Randy! Just 1 more question. Any good site which will teach me regular expressions starting from the very basic?

Comment: I don't know of a good site for absolute beginners, but honestly, there are a seemingly endless number of sites which have regex info.  Above, Guillaume CR suggested regexpal.com -- something like this is great to check out, because it will give you real-time feedback about what your expressions are doing.  You just can't beat hands-on experience.  I'd paste a block of text, or some other formatted material, into the data window on the regexpal.com page and just start playing around.  Regex can be a complicated topic, but the basics are straightforward and will empower you considerably.